# How to move a span tag in an html page multiple times efficiently with find-and-replace or regex or else?

Tags: html, regex, replace

I have a very lengthy html page with multiple instances of this type of code:

```
<h3>Some header text
    <span class="text-small">Text I want to move</span>
</h3>
```

Ideal result:

```
<p>Text I want to move</p>
<h3>Some header text</h3>
```

I can use regex to find all the spans, but then what? Replace doesn't help me since the content is unique each time.

Thanks for your help, and let me know if I left any crucial info out.

Edit:
Per @bloodyKnuckles's comments, adding some more information:
I'm on mac, editing an html locally in Adobe Dreamweaver that will be copied onto a remote server later. The pages already exist there and I am updating some of the code.
In terms of regex, I do not have a lot of experience with it, and I tried a couple of different processors but I can't recall exactly which ones.

Comment: What text processor do you prefer to use to execute your regex? PHP? Javascript? Perl, awk, sed, vim...?

Comment: I'll be honest, this is a new kind of task for me. I found an online testing tool and tried several different ones, but there are so many. If you know a few that are good options for me, I can focus on learning them more in depth, and that would be a great help. Thank you. The page itself is plain html.

Comment: What computer operating system do you use? Windows, Mac, Linux? Is the page a text file on your computer? Is it online? A remove server?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Thanks, I went ahead and edited my question to give more basic information. In terms of your comment, I use a Mac, and I am editing in Dreamweaver. It's just a local copy from our remote server. I will be editing locally then pasting it back in.

Comment: do they all have the class="text-small"?

Comment: @Moob yes they do. That part is consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [link](https://www.askapache.com/software/regular-expressions-in-dreamweaver/) shared by @bloodyKnuckles, I saw this useful tip:

> Use parentheses to set off **groupings** within the regular expression to be referred to later. Then use $1, $2, $3, and so on in the Replace With field to refer to the first, second, third, and later parenthetical groupings.

Finally, my solution worked like this-

Find:

```
(<h3.*)(<span class="text-small">*.+<\/span>)(</h3>)
```

Replace with:

```
$2$1$3
```

Thanks so much, everyone, and thank you @bloodyKnuckles for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Better yet! Accepting your own answer is encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/) for programming on my Mac. ([VIM](https://www.vim.org/) when on the server.) They have a regex-capable find and replace feature. Here's what work with them:

Find: `<h3>(.+)\n *(<span class="text-small">[^<]*</span>)\n</h3>`

Replace: `\2\n<h3>\1</h3>`

Before:

```
<h3>Some header text
    <span class="text-small">Text I want to move</span>
</h3>

<h3>Another header text
    <span class="text-small">Something else.</span>
</h3>
```

After:

```
<span class="text-small">Text I want to move</span>
<h3>Some header text</h3>

<span class="text-small">Something else.</span>
<h3>Another header text</h3>
```

Looks like Dreamweaver uses [something like this](https://www.askapache.com/software/regular-expressions-in-dreamweaver/):

Find: `<h3>(.+)\n *(<span class="text-small">[^<]*</span>)\n</h3>`

Replace: `$2\n<h3>$1</h3>`